# Fabric.js image clipping not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm using fabric.js library and html5 canvas. I have to clip images using objects included in svg. Requirements are images should be added according to same object structure in svg and svg should scaled to fit the canvas. So I was able to do this except, after image masked(clipped) there's unnecessary space. In other words image is not masked correctly. Please see the fiddle

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hydride/pL76s908/)

I loaded svg using string. Then grouped all the objects and scaled it to fit the canvas. After I ungrouped it.

```
var str = '<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ --> <g>  <title>Layer 1</title>  <rect id="svg_1" height="138" width="214" y="51" x="49" fill="#FF0000"/>  <ellipse ry="105.500002" rx="104.000009" id="svg_2" cy="333.500002" cx="157.000009" fill="#FF0000"/> </g></svg>';
var items;
fabric.loadSVGFromString(str, function(objects, options) {
    var groups = new fabric.Group(objects);
        groups.scaleToHeight(canvas.height);
    canvas.centerObject(groups);
        canvas.add(groups); 

    items = groups._objects;
        groups._restoreObjectsState();
        canvas.remove(groups);

    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          canvas.add(items[i]);
          items[i].set('selectable', false);
        }
        canvas.renderAll();
});
```

When image is added I'm masking it by selected object(here items[0]).

```
var imageUrl = 'http://fabricjs.com/assets/pug_small.jpg';
    $('#btn-add').click(function(){
        fabric.Image.fromURL(imageUrl, function (img) {
        img.set({
          left: items[0].left,
          top: items[0].top,
          width :items[0].getBoundingRect().width,
          height: items[0].getBoundingRect().height,                    
        });             
        img.clipTo = function(ctx) {
          items[0]._render(ctx);
        }               
        canvas.add(img).setActiveObject(img);
        canvas.renderAll();
      });
    });
```

Comment: I found that _render use width instead of getWidth. Here I have scaled the object so it should getWidth. Anyone know to correct this?

Comment: @kangax any solution?

Comment: I am facing the same issue after clipping it is moving inside of the rectangle, actually, it should not.